# Why is Facebook not reading OpenGraph Tags in my page?

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph

I have a page I am developing with OpenGraph tags: http://william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org/?qRID=252851

The tags are correctly picked up by other Opengraph page crawlers.

But the Facebook page crawlers are not picking up the same data.

Is there an error in my Opengraph Tags that I can fix?  Or is there an error with FBs process?

UPDATE 10/3: Let me clarify, here are the OpenGraph tags as they are parsed by the parser on "opengraph[DOT]in":
og:site_name: Aesthetic Dentistry
og:title: We're so grateful for good reviews from our customers. Here's another:
og:type: profile
og:url: http://william-j-bennett-iii-dds[DOT]nationaldentalreviews[DOT]org
og:image: http://www[DOT]nationaldentalreviews[DOT]org/Images/StarRating5_119x50.png

Comment: here are the FB link #1 I used to test FB OpenGraph parsing:
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org/?qRID=252851

Comment: here are the FB link #2 I used to test FB OpenGraph parsing: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org%2F%3FqRID%3D252851

Comment: Here is the Opengraph link I used that correctly parsed the OpenGraphTags: http://www.opengraph.in/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwilliam-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org%2F%3FqRID%3D252851&format=html

Comment: You can edit your question (click on the edit link under the question's tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Facebook requires all OpenGraph meta tags parameters, although they're not strictly required by OpenGraph itself. You strictly need to specific the og:url and the og:title meta tags

Comment: Right, I saw those error messages, the linter says that the "og:url" and "og:title" aren't there. But if you look at the source, I explicitly set those values. Also, if you look at any external OpenGraph parsing tool, they all correctly pick up all my Opengraph tags. For example: [link to opengraph.in](http://www.opengraph.in/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwilliam-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org%2F%3FqRID%3D252851&format=html)

Comment: was finally able to get back to fixing this. thanks for your help.
It was the og:url tag

Comment: how did u fix this. I seem to have all the og property tags on my page. Still the Facebook doesn't read them

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in Facebook Linter for [url you provided](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org/?qRID=252851) about missing og:url and og:type properties (both are required by Facebook)

Comment: Right, I saw those error messages, the linter says that the "og:url" and "og:title" aren't there. But if you look at the source, I explicitly set those values.

Also, if you look at any external OpenGraph parsing tool, they all correctly pick up all my Opengraph tags. For example: [link](http://www.opengraph.in/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwilliam-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org%2F%3FqRID%3D252851&format=html)

Comment: can it be related to the XML NS? Your page have xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" but facebook's examples stated 
xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/". Also every og:* property you use have same id attribute "id="ctl00_MetaOgType" which is wrong (not sure if facebook og parser look at this)

Comment: I'll try the namespace change. Also, those ID tags are from Asp.Net, so that I can set the Tag values from the code behind. Here is a Page that is generated the exact same way, but for some reason it does get parsed correctly by FB: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fhelp-desk.nationaldentalreviews.org%2F%3FqRID%3D243126

Answer (score 0):

One other problem is that your OG markup differs between these two URLs:

```
http://william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org/?qRID=252851
```

and

```
http://william-j-bennett-iii-dds.nationaldentalreviews.org/
```

In the first URL you specify og:url as pointing to the latter URL - so the Facebook crawlers follow that link - you need to ensure the markup on the second URL is correct.

Answer (score -1):

There is a fundamental problem in that the Facebook scraper does not follow standard XML syntax. Standard syntax is that ALL attributes must be quoted. Facebook is not allowing quoted attributes and not allowing self-closing elements.